# Check value of input field and add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two input fields and a submit button (displayed inline). I'm trying to add a class to the next sibling after a input field is filled out. So if the first name input field is filled out, add a class to the email input field, if the email input field is filled out, add a class to the next input field and so on...

This is my code so far:

```
$('.form-display #mce-FNAME').blur(function() {
     if($.trim(this.value).length) {
        $('#mce-EMAIL').toggleClass('animated pulse');
     }else if(...){ }...
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-display">
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpoo50qL/4/) it seems to be working. The only thing I can imagine happening is that the class you are adding isn't working the way you want it to. What exactly is `.animated.pulse` ?

Comment: ..the class is working (animate.css). I'm looking for a way to do it not on blur but based on the value of the current input field.. e.g after a single letter or more was typed in an input box, add the class to the next input field...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab all the inputs except the submit button into a collection.

On input, toggle the class of the next input based on whether the current input has a value:

```
var inputs = $('.form-display input').not(':submit');

inputs.on('input', function() {
  $(inputs[inputs.index(this) + 1]).toggleClass('animated pulse', this.value > '');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/me0zsoot/1)

**Snippet:**

```js
var inputs = $('.form-display input').not(':submit');  //all inputs except submit button

inputs.on('input', function() {
  $(inputs[inputs.index(this) + 1]).toggleClass('animated pulse', this.value > '');
});
```

```css
.animated.pulse {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-display">
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-CITY">City </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-STATE">State </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-ZIP">Zip </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
```

Comment: It is working and is exactly what I was looking for... THX!

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpoo50qL/7/)**.

Better to use the both events `blur` and `input` event to track user change on input field and then use `parents()` and `next()` methods after checking if the blured input is empty, check example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('input blur', '.form-display .mc-field-group input',function() {
  if(!$.trim($(this).val()))
  {
    $(this).parents('.mc-field-group').next('.mc-field-group')
           .find('input').addClass('animated pulse');
  }else{
    $(this).parents('.mc-field-group').next('.mc-field-group')
           .find('input').removeClass('animated pulse');
  }
});
```

```css
.animated.pulse {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-display">
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-CITY">City </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="CITY" class="required city" id="mce-CITY">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it not on blur but based on the value of the current input field.. e.g after a single letter or more was typed in an input box, add the class to the next input field...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that would look for current input among all inputs, and then find the next empty input and add the next class:

```
$('input').blur(function() {
     if($.trim(this.value).length) {
       var allInputs = $('input');
       var hasFoundNext = false;
       currentInputIndex = $('input').index(this);

       for (index = currentInputIndex + 1; (index < allInputs.length && !hasFoundNext); index++) {
          if(!$.trim(allInputs[index].value).length) {
            allInputs.eq(index).addClass('next');
            hasFoundNext = true;
          }
       }
     }
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wed0104o/

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, the blur event is the right way to do this.

Here's a working example for you to look at.

```js
$(function() {
  $('form[name=siblings] input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var className = $(this).attr('name') + "-has-value"; //unique class name
    if ($(this).val().match(/.{3,}/)) { //regex to check value - check length of match
      $(this).next().addClass(className); //add class to next
    } else {
      $(this).next().removeClass(className); //remove class from next
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="siblings">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
  <input name="etc" type="text" placeholder="etc..." />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it not on blur but based on the value of the current input field.. e.g after a single letter or more was typed in an input box, add the class to the next input field...

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/sq1mx1rm/

Kind of rough way of doing it, parent() can be heavy.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.mc-field-group').find('input').bind('focusout', function() {
        console.log($(this).parent().next('.mc-field-group').find('input').attr('id'));
        $(this).parent().next('.mc-field-group').find('input').addClass('test')
          });
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="form-display">
          <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
          </div>
          <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
          </div>
          <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-LastName">Last Name </label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-LastName">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add onchange attribute to each inputs.
2) At JS file,make a global collection of inputs.
3) At the changed() function find the index of changed input.
4) Change the class of next input.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the HTML, I would add a class to all the input fields you want to target, otherwise you might be tripped up by a hidden field or another input you didn't want to target.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fieldlist = $('.pulsefield');

    fieldlist.bind('blur', function(){
        var currentElement = $(this);
        if(currentElement.val().length>1){
            var currentIndex = fieldlist.index(currentElement);
            if(currentIndex+1<fieldlist.length){
                var nextElement = $(fieldlist.get(currentIndex+1));
                nextElement.toggleClass('animated pulse');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should set the pulse animation on next sibling fields that are not already filled out as you go through the form.

```js
fieldlist = $('.form-display input');

fieldlist.on('input onpropertychange', function() {
     if ( $(this).val().length ) {
            $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');
            if(( fieldlist.index($(this)) + 1 ) < fieldlist.length - 1){
              target = $(fieldlist.get(fieldlist.index($(this))+1));
                if ( target.val().length === 0 ) {
                  target.addClass('animated pulse');
                }
            }
     }
});

$('.form-display input').first().addClass('pulse');
$('.form-display input').first().focus();
```

```css
@keyframes pulse_animation {
 0% { transform: scale(1); }
 30% { transform: scale(1); }
 40% { transform: scale(0.95); }
 50% { transform: scale(1); }
 60% { transform: scale(1); }
 70% { transform: scale(0.95); }
 80% { transform: scale(1); }
 100% { transform: scale(1); }
}

.pulse {
 animation-name: pulse_animation;
 animation-duration: 500ms;
 transform-origin:70% 70%;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-display">
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" tabindex=1>
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-PHONE">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="phone" value="" name="PHONE" class="required" id="mce-PHONE">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
```